# Por que os caracteres da string estão sendo impressos como números inteiros?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, for

Tenho que analisar um excerto de código e explicar o seu funcionamento, mas não consigo perceber a saída:

#### Código:

```
word_norm = 'mundo'.encode("utf8").lower()
for idx, value in enumerate(word_norm):
    print(idx, value);
```

#### Saída

> ```
> 0 109
> 1 117
> 2 110
> 3 100
> 4 111
> ```

Não percebo o valor da variável `value` do ciclo for. Alguma ideia o que significa o valor inteiro? Estava a espera de ver cada caractere da palavra mundo.

Comment: Não use imagens pra mostrar código ou saídas. É difícil de executar pra quem tá respondendo, difícil de indexar para a busca do site e impossível de entender para usuários de leitores de tela.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A documentação da função [`encode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html) diz que retorna um *array* de *bytes*, portanto é isto que você tem, uma coleção de *bytes*, não de caracteres. Ou não deve usar esta função ou deve usar uma que transforme em *string* novamente `decode()`, o que pode não ser o que desejava fazer.